# Update existing plugin for Twitter 1.1 API

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter

I have been developing a WordPress site for someone which uses the plugin Social Media Mashup which integrates many social media RSS feeds into one.

http://wordpress.org/plugins/social-media-mashup/

Anyway, the site I was working on has been approved and needs to go live this weekend but Twitter updated its API a few nights ago and now the Twitter feed on said plugin no longer works which has left me in a right mess.

I can't get through to the developers and fixing it myself is way out of my virtually non-existent coding experience.

I believe this is the Github https://github.com/bandwidthcom/jhart2wordpress/tree/master/wp-content/plugins/social-media-mashup

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks
Chris

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because Twitter API has been updated from 1 to 1.1. The difference should be on the 169th line in social-media-mashup.php 
user_timeline now uses GET method of an authenticated user, so libraries such as github.com/themattharris/tmhOAuth or github.com/abraham/twitteroauth need to be used.

This question might help: [Twitter API 1.1 issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17090437/twitter-api-1-1-issues)

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your reply. I figured it was the 169th line.  Spent all day on a few different solutions like the ones you mentioned but no luck so far. Think it's my lack of knowledge more than anything though

Comment: Having exact same issue with same plug-in... if you fixed it, would love to know how or get a copy of your fix.  Sounds like will be a lot of work to update the plug-in to use OAuth, when it is just designed for simple/single get of an RSS feed.  For this project I can't just switch to another plug-in.